# How do I check a list of directories from a file, but some entries have multiple directories separated by a comma

Tags: ansible

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
hints_directory: /opt/cassandra/hints
data_file_directory: /opt/cassandra/data,/opt/cassandra/data2
commitlog_directory: /opt/cassandra/commitlog
cdc_raw_directory: /opt/cassandra/cdc_raw
saved_caches_directory: /opt/cassandra/saved_caches
tmp_directory: /opt/cassandra/tmp
jna_directory: /opt/cassandra/jna
dump_directory: /opt/cassandra/dump
```

I want to read that file and check for the existence of each directory using ansible. The tricky part comes on the second line, where the line contains 2 directory paths. How do I get ansible to read each line of the file as in the example below and check for the existence of each directory.

Here is what I have thus far, but it stumbles on the data_file_directory due to having multiple path values for the single line. I've tried to split the line entry, but that doesn't solve the issue.

Thoughts?

```
  - name: Ensure the directories exist
    file:
      path: "{{item.split(':')[1].split(' ')[1].split(',')}}"
      state: directory
    with_lines: cat <<pathtofile>>/directories.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the variables from the file into a dictionary and convert the strings to  lists, e.g.

```yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: directories.txt
        name: dirs_str
    - set_fact:
        dirs_list: "{{ dict(_keys|zip(_vals)) }}"
      vars:
        _keys: "{{ dirs_str.keys()|list }}"
        _vals: "{{ dirs_str.values()|map('split', ',')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  dirs_list:
    cdc_raw_directory:
    - /opt/cassandra/cdc_raw
    commitlog_directory:
    - /opt/cassandra/commitlog
    data_file_directory:
    - /opt/cassandra/data
    - /opt/cassandra/data2
    dump_directory:
    - /opt/cassandra/dump
    hints_directory:
    - /opt/cassandra/hints
    jna_directory:
    - /opt/cassandra/jna
    saved_caches_directory:
    - /opt/cassandra/saved_caches
    tmp_directory:
    - /opt/cassandra/tmp
```

Select and flatten the values, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        allDirectories: "{{ dirs_list.values()|flatten }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  allDirectories:
  - /opt/cassandra/hints
  - /opt/cassandra/data
  - /opt/cassandra/data2
  - /opt/cassandra/commitlog
  - /opt/cassandra/cdc_raw
  - /opt/cassandra/saved_caches
  - /opt/cassandra/tmp
  - /opt/cassandra/jna
  - /opt/cassandra/dump
```

, or use the expression directly in the loop

```yaml
  - name: Ensure the directories exist
    file:
      path: "{{ item }}"
      state: directory
    loop: "{{ dirs_list.values()|flatten }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that may have a similar exercise, I have figured out how to do this:

```
  - set_fact:
         allDirectories: []

  - set_fact:
         allDirectories: "{{ item.split(':')[1].split(' ')[1].split(',')  + allDirectories}}"
    with_lines: cat <<pathtofile>>/directories.txt

  - name: Ensure the directories exist
    file:
      path: "{{item}}"
      state: directory
    with_items: "{{allDirectories}}"
```